# Python WTF forms, import error, no module named flask_wtf

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

Im having trouble with flask_wtf, it keeps saying theres no module found with that name.

Ive read on another question that it could be to do with the virtual environment.

*(I don't think my question is the same as that questions as Im clearly showing in my question that Ive installed flask-wtf whilst in my virtual environment. Also all the answers to that question do not seems to solve my problem, so I think if someone can solve my problem having this question active on stack exchange would be a big help to future people with this issue)*

At the top of my script I have

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from flask_wft import FlaskForm
```

and visual studio code is already flagging the flask_wtf as an error saying, no module named flask_wtf.

When I try and run my app.py I get

```
(env) (base) Benjamats-Air:helloPython benjamattesjaroen$ python3 app.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_wft import FlaskForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wft'
```

So clearly I'm still in my virtual environment bellow when I try to install flask-wtf but it says its already installed.

```
(env) (base) Benjamats-Air:helloPython benjamattesjaroen$ pip install flask-wtf

Requirement already satisfied: flask-wtf in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask-wtf) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask-wtf) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->flask-wtf) (1.1.1)
```

So why then does it say theres no module named flask_wtf ?

Comment: Typo: change `from flask_wft import FlaskForm` to `from flask_wtf import FlaskForm`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is a typo error.
While importing from the package, you used flask_wft, but while installing its 
pip install flask-wtf. The t and f if you notice.